# Editing JSON data from within a shopify liquid page

Tags: jquery, json, shopify

New to shopify and the liquid library, I have a customer who needs product pages to be a bit custom. One collection of items product page does not look similar to another.

My plan is to simply toggle on/off the JSON settings that display the unwanted elements.

```
*Pseudocode*
If "product is in collection that doesnt need this element"
   " JSON that displays it = false"
```

How exactly do I access that JSON object from within the liquid pages? Also, is this the best way to go about doing this?

My other thought was to just show/hide the element based on whether its needed.

Answer (score 0):

product.liquid has this script at the very end of liquid -

```
<script>
  products.id{{ product.id }} = {{ product | json }};
</script>
```

Two things you can do here:

1. Assign a different product liquid template for particular products through admin panel/app and design the templates accordingly
2. Use a specific product property/field for each product to differentiate it from others and store it in a ***JS or liquid*** variable when the page loads; which can be used for your **on/off** logic.