# Accessing settings json file in shopify from JS or product liquid page

Tags: shopify

I check this and it wasn't the same as my question:
[Editing JSON data from within a shopify liquid page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873553/editing-json-data-from-within-a-shopify-liquid-page)

Currently I have a file `settings_data.json` in my theme.  This file has a specific field called `"product_form_style"` there is a specific field I need to edit here from one product template titled: `product_custom_liquid`

According to some scarce resource I read this would work:

```
{% settings.product_form_style == 'my value' %}
```

This however gives an error: "Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag 'settings'"

The official documentation says I can access it with ajax or jquery from js however it doesn't give any examples.  It only says it can be done but I have no idea how.

The basic idea is if product template is 'product_custom' then change settings product_form_style == true.

Obviously the above is not correct syntax.  Just an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the `settings_data.json` from the front-end without using an APP.

If you could modify it without any authentication this would have been a huge security issue and anyone could modify it.

`settings_data.json` is modified only when you save something in your Customize panel. For any other way you will need a Private app or some App to do so.

In addition you can't modify files in any way from the liquid code as well. The liquid template language only outputs data, it can't modify that data without the use of some kind of an APP.